# React production build Express listener or server isn't running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, package.json

I'm having issues with the express listener

[image]

[image]

I have also setup my proxy on package.json

Error

[image]

Comment: Code is preferred to images as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Create React App?

Do not use absolute path for the request path, use a relative one instead.

`axios.post("/")`

And double check your `package.json` includes

`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`